# Setting up Django environments for Python2.X and 3.X?

Tags: python, linux, django, ubuntu

I'm trying to set up a Django environment to work on a website project for my Python group.  We're using 2.7 for the project, but when I followed this guide https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/django-install-ubuntu-14.04/ it only set it up for 3.4.  How can I differentiate which set of setup tools it installs?

Here is my pip version when I type `--version`

```
~ $ pip --version
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py3.4.egg (python 3.4)
```

Comment: I dont think so, in the link, they set it up for python 2.7

Comment: When I typed exactly what they said it defaulted to my 3.4 installation instead of 2.7.  How can I tell which version of Django I've installed?

Comment: you can point to python version via `-p`. like this: `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.6 <path/to/new/virtualenv/>` while creating new virtualenv. if it doesnot work, then you have only python 3.4 installed on your machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can point to python executable via `-p`:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 <path/to/new/virtualenv/>
```

while creating your new virtualenv.